# Find all $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ st for any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, the multiset $\{(f(xf(y)+1),f(yf(x)-1)\}$ equals the multiset $\{xf(f(y))+1,yf(f(x))-1\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that for any $x,y \in \mathbb R$, the multiset $\{(f(xf(y)+1),f(yf(x)-1)\}$ is identical to the multiset $\{xf(f(y))+1,yf(f(x))-1\}$.

Note: The multiset $\{a,b\}$ is identical to the multiset $\{c,d\}$ if and only if $a=c,b=d$ or $a=d,b=c$.

My idea

Let's consider the given functional equation

$$\{(f(xf(y)+1), f(yf(x)-1)\} = \{xf(f(y))+1, yf(f(x))-1\}$$
From this, we can derive that $$f(xf(y)+1) = xf(f(y))+1$$ and $f(yf(x)-1) = yf(f(x))-1$  for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

now. We analyze each part:

1. $f(xf(y)+1) = xf(f(y))+1$
2. $f(yf(x)-1) = yf(f(x))-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(xf(y)+1)=xf(y)+1
$$
and let $x=0$ we have
$$
f(1)=1
$$
now consider $y=1$, $\tilde{x}=x-1$ we have
$$
f(x)=x-1+1=x
$$
so the only function that satisfies this functional equation is the identity

You also need to consider the other possible option *i.e.*
$$
f(xf(y)+1)=yf(f(x))-1
$$
And
$$
f(yf(x)-1)=xf(f(y))+1$$
By letting $x=0$ we obtain
$$
f(\pm 1)=yf(f(0))\mp 1
$$
so $f(\pm 1)=\mp 1$. By direct verification
$$
f(x)=-x$$ satisfy the functional equation, I guess it is the only function, but I wasn't able to prove it